# VSCode integrated bash terminal on MacOS Ventura 13.1 not showing paths

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I was working on a project and realized my integrated terminal stopped showing paths. I can still cd into any directory and the "ls" command works properly. How can I fix this?

NOTE: I've recently installed a terminal autocomplete application called Fig. My external terminal works as it should

Current settings in VSCode's settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "args": ["-l"],
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": ["-l"]
    },
    "fish": {
      "path": "fish",
      "args": ["-l"]
    },
    "tmux": {
      "path": "tmux",
      "icon": "terminal-tmux"
    },
    "pwsh": {
      "path": "pwsh",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    }
  },
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Light Pink",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "FIG_NEW_SESSION": "1"
  },
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": []
}
```

I've tried fixing by adding the following and restarting VSCode:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "args": ["-l"],
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": ["-l"]
    },
    "fish": {
      "path": "fish",
      "args": ["-l"]
    },
    "tmux": {
      "path": "tmux",
      "icon": "terminal-tmux"
    },
    "pwsh": {
      "path": "pwsh",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    }
  },
```

But nothing changed

EDIT:
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCmJx.png)

Comment: What do you mean "stops showing paths"? Can you edit a (textual) transcript that demonstrates the problem into the question?

Comment: You might try manually sourcing your ~/.bash_profile in the VS Code terminal.  It may be that the installation of the `Fig` application altered your profile.  Per @CharlesDuffy showing the issue in your question would

Comment: Usually this is a simple matter of customizing the prompt in your bash config - but I'm not sure why this is a problem in VSCode and not in a terminal window opened outside of VSCode. As far as I know, VSCode does nothing to alter the prompt in an integrated terminal. It is certainly possible Fig is doing something.

Comment: Note **textual**. Screenshots don't count towards meeting [mre] requirements; see [Why not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
unset POSIX_CORRECT
```